# "Transport failed to connect to server" when sending mail from Excel through Office 365

Tags: excel, vba, email, smtp

I'm trying to change an old excel form to send email through an Office 365 account instead of GMail, but almost everything I do gives me a `The transport failed to connect to the server` error.

Here is the relevant code:

```vb
Set CDO_Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
On Error GoTo Error_Handling

Const cdoSendUsingPickup = 1                'Send message using the local SMTP service pickup directory.
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2                  'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).

Const cdoAnonymous = 0                      'Do not authenticate
Const cdoBasic = 1                          'basic (clear-text) authentication
Const cdoNTLM = 2                           'NTLM

Set CDO_Config = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
CDO_Config.Load -1

Set SMTP_Config = CDO_Config.Fields '

With SMTP_Config
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.office365.com"
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = cdoNTLM
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = strFrom
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = emailFromPassword
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
    .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
    .Update
End With

With CDO_Mail
    Set .Configuration = CDO_Config
End With

CDO_Mail.Subject = strSubject
CDO_Mail.From = strFrom
CDO_Mail.To = strTo
CDO_Mail.HTMLBody = strBody
CDO_Mail.CC = strCc
CDO_Mail.BCC = strBcc
CDO_Mail.Send

Error_Handling:
If Err.Description <> "" Then
MsgBox (Err.Description)
```

I've tried everything relevant that I can think of (and then some):

- `smtp.office365.com` and `pod51010.office365.com` for the server
- Ports 25, 465, 587
- Toggling SSL
- Removing the connection timeout
- Changing the send using method
- Changing the authentication method

Most all cases give me the error mentioned earlier. Some hang indefinitely (such as using port 25).

Turning SSL off does let a connection through on port 587. Even if we were okay with this, it gives a different error. `The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 530 5.7.57 SMTP; Client was not authenticated to send anonymous mail during MAIL FROM [...outlook.com]` However, I've already verified the credentials are correct. From what I've read this means I can't send mail with SSL off? So that isn't an option anyways.

I'm using Excel 2010.

Am I missing something, or is this not doable for some reason?

Comment: firewall ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522051/trouble-sending-email-to-office-365?rq=1

Comment: No, sadly. I ended up just writing something new in C# and presenting that to my supervisor.